# Is it possible to transition from one material to another in bge?

Tags: materials, game-engine, uv

I want to have different skydomes for different areas of my game world, but I'd prefer not to have them abruptly cut from one to the next. Is there a method to slowly introduce a new material, while the old one fades away? Thanks in advance! Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Might be easier to just fade between textures in the same material instead.

Comment: You can use node editor and animate the mix factor between the materials.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new material and apply it to the dome, then enable *Use Shader Nodes* on this material.

Then open Node editor and add your 2 material nodes you want to interchange and  pass them through Mix RGB node.

To switch between the materials animate the Mix Factor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I can't believe I never knew you could use nodes in blender game like this. So, I could probably use this with numerous materials all attached through the same output, right? And just have a different action actuators for each?

Comment: @Zenet Yes you can have as many materials you want, the node editor is very similar to Cycles